# How to Configure My Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers to List All Possible Constructors in Intelligence

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, ide, intellisense

I'm surprised by the default behavior of my Eclipse Java IDE Intelligence.

If you check the String class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, you will see that there are many constructors. But when I type `String s = new String(`, it does NOT give me any constructor candidates/prototypes from the Intelligence, which is really disappointing me... (But if I type `String.`, it will list all possible candidates)

Do you guys know how to configure my IDE?

Also it's pretty bad that nothing is displayed in Intelligence when I type `String s = new`. It should give me the String constructor candidates.

BTW, I'm from C#, Microsoft Visual C# IDE is much better than Eclipse Java IDE in terms of the Intelligence.

Please help me find out where I could find the configure options so that my Eclipse IDE Intelligence works better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to:

```
Window > Preferences > Java/Editor/Content Assist
```

and change the settings, or you can use `ctrl + space`.

Comment: Hmmm, where is the option I need to configure for the constructor candidates in Intelligence?

Comment: Its called "java proposals"

Comment: No. It does NOT work.  I still don't get the constructor candidates in Intelligence.

Comment: You are obviously doing it wrong. Make sure you have checked the boxes  and applied the settings. Try restarting eclipse. The settings are there and it is those settings that needs to be activated

Comment: I checked all available options in `Windows > Preferences > Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced`, and clicked `Apply`, and then I restarted Eclipse, still not working.